# I am completely new to parquet files and python, Can anyone please let me know how to read parquet file with headers in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, parquet

I am completely new to parquet files and python, Can anyone please let me know how to read parquet file with headers in pyspark and how to specify other options  like we have it in csv files as below:

```
df = spark.read.load("examples/src/main/resources/people.csv",
                     format="csv", sep=":", inferSchema="true", header="true")
```

Answer (score 1):

[Parquet](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/read-parquet.html) files will have `column names in them` and We don't need to specify options like `header`..etc while reading parquet files.

**To read parquet files:**

```
#read parquet file
df=spark.read.parquet("<parquet_file_path>")

#or spark defaultly reads data in parquet format
df=spark.read.load("<parquet_file_path>")

#see data from the dataframe
df.show()
```